# ValueError when using pip or easy_install to install a package into winpython

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, astropy

Currently doing a science course and using python to do calculations and plotting. The Uni uses **winpython 2.7.5.3** This is the version I've installed as it has all the standard packages I need. I'm using **windows 7 64bit**

However my course has started diverging and I need to install additional packages, specifically Astropy.

Initially I had a vcvarsall.bat error, this was fixed by installing Visual C++ 2008 express.

After this both the included version 1.4.1 of pip and easy_install-2.7 find the correct packages but on installing give me an error:

> File
>   "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line
>   29 9, in query_vcvarsall
>
> ```
> raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
> ```
>
> ValueError: [u'path']

I am unfortunately stuck at this point. This is the first of a few packages I need to install, hopefully this is a single error I can fix for all of them

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, to my knowledge Astropy does not compile with MSVC at this time (something I've been meaning to work on).  I currently build the Windows binaries with MinGW gcc, but that's not something most users should attempt to set up themselves (which is why binaries are distributed for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Windows, but I would suggest trying to use a Python distribution such as [Anaconda Python Distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) which should both have Windows versions, and include a whole bunch of packages by default (including Numpy, Scipy, IPython, Matplotlib, and Astropy). The first is free, while the second has free licenses for students and academics.

Comment: I'll look into both of them, thanks I have been told to look into MinGW, however I'm not familiar with this and so far failing to find enough documentation on it.

Comment: Thank you

After a bit of messing about Anaconda allows me to install the packages I require, only issue I have now is a montage wrapper issue with APLpy, I'll work on it.

Thanks!