# Can't install python Polyglot package on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, polyglot

I'm trying to install Polyglot package by using the command:

```
pip install polyglot
```

and I receive the following:

```
Collecting polyglot
  Using cached polyglot-15.10.03-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycld2>=0.3 (from polyglot)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures>=2.1.6 in d:\program files\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from polyglot)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wheel>=0.23.0 in d:\program files\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from polyglot)
Collecting PyICU>=1.8 (from polyglot)
  Using cached PyICU-1.9.3.tar.gz
Collecting morfessor>=2.0.2a1 (from polyglot)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.7.3 in d:\program files\winpython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages (from polyglot)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyICU
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyICU ... error
  Complete output from command "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\revuze\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-h2bmp43j\\PyICU\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpphoimlejpip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  copying icu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  copying PyICU.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  copying docs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
  running build_ext
  building '_icu' extension
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h2bmp43j\PyICU\setup.py", line 115, in <module>
      py_modules=['icu', 'PyICU', 'docs'])
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 49, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run
      _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
      vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
      return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
      raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
  ValueError: ['path']

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for PyICU
  Running setup.py clean for PyICU
Failed to build PyICU
Installing collected packages: pycld2, PyICU, morfessor, polyglot
  Running setup.py install for PyICU ... error
    Complete output from command "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\revuze\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-h2bmp43j\\PyICU\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-lkjedrat-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying icu.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying PyICU.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying docs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    running build_ext
    building '_icu' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h2bmp43j\PyICU\setup.py", line 115, in <module>
        py_modules=['icu', 'PyICU', 'docs'])
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 49, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
        return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
      File "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\revuze\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-h2bmp43j\\PyICU\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-lkjedrat-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\revuze\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-h2bmp43j\PyICU\
```

At first I had a problem with the C++ Compiler which I resolved and now I get this problem. Iv'e searched for similar issues and most of the comments recommend to install Microsoft Windows SDK (in order to resolve a 64 bits issue with the compiler) which I did without luck.

I'm working on Windows 10 64 machine on Python 3.4.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609520/valueerror-when-using-pip-or-easy-install-to-install-a-package-into-winpython?rq=1 ? it looks related albeit old ... but same path entry missing ...

Comment: https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/91#issuecomment-281948218 here is the answer for this question. Worked for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sadly the package is not yet stable when it comes to Windows.  After trying pip and conda install without luck. This is what I did to get it to work on Python 3.6 environment running on Windows 10 64 bit.

I had Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools(includes Windows SDK) via VS 2015 Community version and Numpy already installed.

I downloaded the correct dependence packages(PyICU and pycld2) from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and:

```
pip install PyICU-1.9.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install pycld2-0.31-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

So cp36 matches my Python env.version, win for Windows, and amd64 for 64bits. Download the correct wheel that matches your systems.

After that I cloned and install the package from GitHub

```
git clone https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git
cd polyglot
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was able to install polyglot in my machine without any errors. But when i try to run the tests, it says unable to import polyglot. Do you have any idea what might be causing the error?

Comment: Which Python version(s) are you using? Do you have multiple Pythons in your system? When you do: where pip, what path does it give you?

Comment: I did install the above mentioned two packages, and saved the github tar.gz file locally on my drive, now i get the error: no matching distribution found for future>2.1.6 any ideas for that

Comment: for me it's throwing error 
```This backport is meant only for Python 2.
It does not work on Python 3, and Python 3 users do not need it as the concurrent.futures package is available in the standard library.
For projects that work on both Python 2 and 3, the dependency needs to be conditional on the Python version, like so:
extras_require={':python_version == "2.7"': ['futures']}
error: Setup script exited with 1```

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to install polyglot do follow steps:

Use `git` to install `polyglot` if you don't have then conda install git and then use this command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot@master
```

the file will be automatically downloaded from this site, don't have to install again.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to download from https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/tarball/master and then

```
python pip install aboSamoor-polyglot-15.10.03-69-gaf5059f.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have now Windows vs2010 compiler, you may try this:

- launch "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\make_cython_use_vc.bat"
- then launch "Winpython Command Prompt" and "pip install polyglot"

If it fails, to revert to previous situation:

- launch "D:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\make_cython_use_mingw.bat"

Answer (score -2):

As I suspect that you do not have good experience compiling code on Windows it could be a better for your to try the use of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) python distribution which has most of the Python packages already compiled.

Once install you just use `conda` instead of `pip` to install new packages. You can still use pip if you have to.