# unable to install polyglot on windows

Tags: python, installation, polyglot

i was trying to install polyglot package and i received the following error
i couldn't understand what's the problem any suggestions ?

```
>pip install polyglot
Collecting polyglot
  Using cached polyglot-16.7.4.tar.gz (126 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\emnat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x18coqx5\polyglot_e6abe02e82ee4abca307c4c2430b029c\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          readme = readme_file.read()
        File "c:\users\emnat\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4941: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512311/cant-install-python-polyglot-package-on-windows

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: pip install git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot@master